# Unable to find out how to edit Titles from horizontal menu [prestashop 1.6]

Tags: drop-down-menu, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm unable to find out where can I edit horizontal menu using PrestaShop 1.6.

I can add/remove entries but not edit them.

I want to edit `Všetci výrobcovia` to `Výrobcovia` which basically means `All manufacters` to just `Manufacters`.

> img - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtqQk.png
>
> menu -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E65EK.png

So I tried looking it up in `SETTINGS - CMS`, but with no luck.

I looked into DB and tried to find it in many tables. Even in localisation. Still nothing

[sorry for posting here, I even tried to register on prestashopforum, yet I did not receive any confirmation email, so I'm here - first time using PrestaShop]

So it seems I'm unable to figured it out alone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am trying to show below is a workaround for v2.2.1 of `ps_mainmenu` module installed in PS 1.7.5.0. I don't think there is a difference with the version you are installing in your PS 1.6.

In the module configuration page, there is a part enabling you to create a link (second part). It contains 2 main inputs : Label and Link.

In label, put Výrobcovia.
In link, put the link to manufactures page, e.g, if the current manufacturers link is `localhost/abc`, add it in the input.

Then click on add.

You will see your new link in the first part of config page (like in your first imgur). Add it to your menu in the left part.

Delete the `Všetci výrobcovia`.

There is for sure a solution that consists by editing the module or by adding a translation. I will be back here if I find it.

**Edit**
You can see from the module [code source](https://github.com/PrestaShop/ps_mainmenu/blob/v2.1.1/ps_mainmenu.php#L416) that there are many places where the string 'All brands' is translated. The module uses this string instead of 'brands'. Since it is discouraged to modify built-in module files, I would go and change in the translations by putting `Výrobcovia` as translation of 'All brands'.

I hope it helped.

Comment: HI! 

How did i not see this..Now i can see it all clearly! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean a module `Top horizontal menu` (but in other cases the way should be the same). The easiest way to achieve your goal is to manage your translations. In your admin panel go to **Localization -> Translations** and in a section **Modify translations** in the first select choose *Installed modules translations*, in the second choose a theme for which you want to change the field or core if you want to change it for all themes, in the third choose a language you want to change and press **Modify** button. In the result page, find your module and expand a translation section. Find your variable inside and change it as you wish

Comment: I just rewrite them in file via ftp, but thnak you for answering :)